# ggplot: Create a bar plot of multiple counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

Working with a data set that has `user_ids` and `number_of_visits` they have visited a specific location (geo_location). I am trying to get a bar plot where `y` axis reflecting `total_number_of_users` and `x` reflecting condition such as:

- 3 or more visits
- 5 or more visits
- 10 or more visits

  `user_id, number_of_visits
  0001, 12
  0002,  3
  0003,  1
  0004, 34
  0005, 11
  0006,  8`

using count seems like an overkill since it creates logical table. Since no grouping involve use of dplyr seems like not an option.

`count(df, number_of_visits >= 3, number_of_visits >=5)`

`df %>% number_of_visits(count3 = number_of_visits >= 3)`

Comment: Do you want `hist(df$number_of_visits)`?

Comment: sorry should have mentioned massive longtail

Comment: You could extract the relevant counts and bins - look at the output of `dput(hist(df$number_of_visits))` and `hist(df$number_of_visits)$counts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(user_id = c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006"),
                number_of_visits = c(12,3,1,34,11,8))

df = df %>%
  mutate(threeOrMore = ifelse(number_of_visits >= 3, ">=3", "<3")) %>%
  mutate(fiveOrMore = ifelse(number_of_visits >= 5, ">=5", "<5")) %>%
  mutate(tenOrMore = ifelse(number_of_visits >= 10, ">=10", "<10"))

plot = ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(threeOrMore))

print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: you can use `case_when` in a single `mutate` rather than 3 with 3 `ifelse`.